# Angular : remove straight lines points using Leaflet map

Tags: angular, leaflet, polyline

I'm try developing a flights tracker using Leaflet map API . Every certain time when there are any new coordinates point position of aircraft so to display them on map , i have "connection" between the last and the first point as straight lines overlap with existing original polyline of flight path due using interval function to check new coordinates point position . My question is how can i remove straight lines ?  .

example what i have : [link](https://ibb.co/SVqTG6f)

My code

```
export class MapTrackBeforPage implements OnInit {
    map: Map;
    poly:L.Polyline


    constructor(
        private http: HTTP,
       public zone : NgZone) {

    }


    ionViewDidEnter() {
        this.getmarker().then(() => {
            this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
                interval(15000).subscribe(() => {
                  ---- Reload DATA
                    this.getmarker()
                })
            })
        })

        // In setView add latLng and zoom
        this.map = new Map('Map_id', { attributionControl: false }).setView([33, 44], 6);
        this.sourceFlightPath.addTo(this.map)
        return tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/transport-dark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=', {
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }

    ---- GETTING DATA --------
    async getmarker() {
        this.http.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', {}, {})
            .then(data => {

                this.AddPath(getdata)

            })
    }

------ PATH OF AIRCRAFT -----
    AddPath(path) {
        // Flight path

        for (let datas of path['trail']) {

         new L.Polyline([datas.lat,datas.lng], { color: 'red', weight: 3 }).addTo(this.map);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug it? Which items do you have in 'path' at 'AddPath'? Does 'path' contains all of the points of a flight route or only new points which have been added since previous iteration?

Comment: Yes , l have all data Json in `AddPath` and contains all of the points of a flight route

Comment: I think this is the problem. Each time when you call 'AddPAth' you have to pass only new points to it. Otherwise you have to clear the map before adding route on it (and I don't see it in your code). Most likely you have the following situation: iteration 1 brings points A,B,C to the map; iteration 2 brings A,B,C,D. As a result you will draw A,B,C,A,B,C,D - and here is where you have a line drawn between C->A. And the same thing will happen with each next iteration

Comment: can you modify my code please , because i am stack in this problem more then 1 month

Comment: As an option, you can store the count of points which are already drawn and on each new iteration draw only new points which are located at the end of an array. You can find sample at:  https://gist.github.com/ilchenkob/d2025b94215469c2f88a5ac3b1c99c7b

Comment: i have error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBounds' of undefined`